What are some good medium matrices with known eigenvectors?
I am trying to test if an eigendecomposition I have is working properly. For this I would like some matrices that are 10x10 (ish) with trivial (or known) eigenvectors and eigenvalues so that I can test my results.
Obviously there are infinitely many eigenvectors since scalar multiples of eigenvectors are eigenvectors.
However, some are better than others, for example, a scaling matrix has a single eigen value with a large multiplicity, so every vector is an eigenvector, thus any answer is a good answer, making it a rather useless test case.

Circulant matrices?

@IanBush useful, I did not know of them. I would prefer it if the eigenvectors had real valued entries though, if possible

Are your matrices symmetric? Why do you want to do this and not use LAPACK?

The eigenvectors of the central differences of $d_{xx}$ on a grid with reflecting boundary conditions (or Dirichlet boundary conditions) are known and real. See the discrete case here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_the_second_derivative
So you can construct a grid with 10 vertices and compute on it.

You can create them yourself. Create random $V$, $D$, and compute $A = V D V^{-1}$. This allows you to test more cases without hassle, and specify the distribution of eigenvalues and the condition number of the eigenvector matrix $\kappa(V)$, which are the main parameters that affect the stability of your results under perturbations.
Note that a good eigenvalue algorithm should be backward stable: the computed matrices should satisfy $\tilde{V}\tilde{D}\tilde{V}^{-1} = A + O(\|A\|)\mathsf{u}$, where $\mathsf{u}$ is the machine precision. Whether you can expect $\tilde{D} - D$, $\tilde{V} - V$ and $\tilde{V}^{-1}-V^{-1}$ to be small depends on the conditioning of the problem. To ensure that the problem is well-conditioned in your initial tests, you can ensure that $\kappa(V)$ is small and that the entries of $D$ are well spaced one from the other.
